# Why font-size property used on div affects divs width and height?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a fixed width and height div element which width/heigth changes when font-size property applied to it, **Why?**

I thought font-size affects only fonts size but not the container where it sits.

Comment: this is called "overflow".

Comment: If you have text inside this div, the fact of changing font-size will change the size of the text and has an impact to the size of his container (your div in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The `width` and `height` properties set the desired properties for an element, which means that the element may update it's size to fit the content.

If you wish to be restrict about sizing, you can use the `overflow` property to update how it handles oversized content.

Examples:
`overflow: hidden`: everything outside of the `width` and `height` won't be displayed
`overflow: scroll`: the element has a scroll to show what's beyond `width` and `height`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

It may also be worth checking out `min-width`, `max-width`, `min-height` and `max-height`depending on your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of your `display` properties.

`display:table` and `display:inline` both will adapt to your content's size even if you set a fixed width and height.

Try `display:flex` or `display:block` on your div and adjust the `overflow` settings to your will (if you want the overflowed content to show or not) and you should be good.